# How to get first two directories of path

Tags: linux, bash

I have a path in linux bash script in a variable. This path could be

```
/a/b/c/d/t.json
/a/b/c/d/e/f/t.json
/a/b/t.json
```

I want to get the first 2 directories. The output should be `/a/b` for all 3 example paths above.

Comment: please edit  your question to include what have you tried. Good luck.

Answer (score 19):

try:

```
 echo "$pathvar" | cut -d/ -f 1-3
```